Why windows.scrollY value is not changing even though I scroll?
So, here is my code:
 const [color, setColor] = useState(false);

 function changeColor() {
   const scrolled = window.scrollY > 60;
   console.log(scrolled);
 }

 window.addEventListener(
   "scroll",
   function () {
     changeColor();
   },
   true
);

I do not why the scrollY value is not changing even though I scroll

it could be that you are scrolling within a container instead of in the document root, id check for any overflow within your html and attach your event listener to that instead of the window.

As Devon suggested, can you also please post the HTML or a rough mockup of your screen elements to understand why it's not working for you? Your code is correct; it gives true once you have scrolled 60 units from the top of the document, so scrollY is certainly changing.
